# and call the election a virtual toss-up

Tags: sentence-construction

> **Given all this uncertainty, it is tempting to conclude that it is too early for predictions, and call the election a virtual toss-up.** That is the view of bettors, who currently make Mr Biden a bare 55-45 favourite. Yet a hard look at the data and at history suggests that this is too generous to Mr Trump. The Economist’s first-ever statistical forecast of an American presidential race, which we launch this week and will update every day until the election, gives Mr Biden an 82% chance of victory.

---

link :　https://www.economist.com/united-states/2020/06/11/meet-our-us-2020-election-forecasting-model

My question is:

"and call the election a virtual toss-up.", is it a compound structure to "to conclude", or a parenthesis to " it is too early for predictions"?

- it is tempting to conclude .. , and it is tempting to call ..?
- it is too early for prediction, and it is too early to call..?

Comment: it is too early for prediction, and it is too early to call.  Given all this uncertainty, it is tempting to conclude that it is too early to predict the successful outcome of any of the candidates, and, therefore, we are saying that each candidate has an equal chance of success

Comment: Thank you, now I got the sentence meaning. But grammatically, when "to" is omitted from "call", shouldn't it be coincide to "to conclude"?

Comment: Look at this:  'I'm tempted to call it quits and go home'............vs............'I'm tempted to call it quits and to go home'.    I like the first.

Comment: Yes, and then according to what you said, the sentence should be "it is tempting to conclude .., and call ..", not your previous answer.

Comment: I read it as meaning, "It is too early for predictions [and, therefore], it is too early to call."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reading here, guided mostly by meaning and not applying grammar rules, is that #

> It is tempting to conclude that it is too early to predictions

> [It is tempting to] call the election a virtual toss-up.

These two sentences concur: We can't yet predict the winner.

The alternate is hard to make work

> It is too early for predictions

> [It is too early for] call the election...

The second sentence doesn't work as "for call" isn't correct.

The second sentence also is semantically odd.  It says "It is too early to say that we don't know who will win." (surely it can never be too *early* for that).

So I conclude "call" is parallel to "conclude", however I don't think this writing is particularly clear.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't get it when you said it is semantically odd. It seems make sense to me.